Unable to fetch name based on user id
I am trying to fetch names of the user whose user id is entered in the profile section but I get some format exception error that I am not able to resolve however the fetched name is being displayed on the terminal but not in the emulator.
I am using Flutter in Android studio, and Springboot in IntelliJ Idea Community Edition 2023.3.4 , and MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE.
If the name shows up in the Flutter Terminal but not in the emulator, then probably there is a problem in the way I am handling the response from the server at the frontend. I need help here.
Here is all my code:
Flutter:-
1.) profile.dart:
import 'dart:ffi';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_dashboard/pages/home/widgets/activity_details_card.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter_dashboard/responsive.dart';
import 'package:flutter_dashboard/const.dart';
import 'package:flutter_dashboard/widgets/profile/widgets/scheduled.dart';
import 'package:flutter_dashboard/widgets/weightHeightBloodCard.dart';
class Profile extends StatefulWidget {
  final void Function(String) onUserIdChanged;
  const Profile({Key? key, required this.onUserIdChanged}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _ProfileState createState() => _ProfileState();
}

class _ProfileState extends State<Profile> {
  late TextEditingController userIdController;
  String profileName = ""; // Add a variable to store the profile name
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    userIdController = TextEditingController();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    userIdController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  Future<void> fetchProfileName(String userId) async {
    final url = Uri.parse('http://192.168.0.194:3030/getNameById/$userId');
    final headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer your-auth-token',
    };
    try {
      final response = await http.get(url, headers: headers);
      // Perform your API request here to fetch the profile name
      // Replace this with your actual API call
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        // If the request is successful, update the profile name
        setState(() {
          profileName = jsonDecode(response.body)['profileName'];
        });
      } else {
        // Handle errors
        print('Failed to fetch profile name: ${response.statusCode}');
        print('Response body: ${response.body}');
      }
    } catch (error) {
      // Handle errors
      print('Error fetching profile name: $error');
    }
  }




  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
          bottomLeft: Radius.circular(Responsive.isMobile(context) ? 10 : 30.0),
          topLeft: Radius.circular(Responsive.isMobile(context) ? 10 : 30.0),
        ),
        color: cardBackgroundColor,
      ),
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              const SizedBox(
                height:   50,
              ),
              // Image.asset(
              //   "assets/images/ultra-instinct-mastered-resized.png",
              // ),
              // const SizedBox(
              //   height: 15,
              // ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 2,
              ),
              Text(
                "Edit health details",
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 12,
                  color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                ),
              ),
              // TextField(
              //   controller: userIdController,
              //   decoration: InputDecoration(
              //     labelText: 'User ID',
              //     hintText: 'Enter user ID',
              //   ),
              // ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              TextField(
                controller: userIdController,
                onChanged: (userId) {
                  widget.onUserIdChanged(userId); // Notify parent widget
                  fetchProfileName(userId); // Fetch profile name
                },
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'User ID',
                  hintText: 'Enter user ID',
                ),
              ),
              Text(
                profileName.isNotEmpty ? profileName : "Poopie",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
              ),
             ElevatedButton(
               onPressed: () {
            // Fetch data or perform any action here
               },
               child: Text('Confirm'),
             ),
              // Add other widgets as needed
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
 }

Springboot:-
1.) EmployeeController.java:
package com.example.test.controller;


import com.example.test.model.EmployeeDetails;
import com.example.test.repository.EmployeeRepo;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;


import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping
public class EmployeeController {

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeRepo employeeRepo;

    @GetMapping("/getall")
    public List<EmployeeDetails> getall(){
        return employeeRepo.findAll();
    }

    @GetMapping("/getByName/{name}")
    public List<EmployeeDetails> getByName(@PathVariable String name) {
        return employeeRepo.findByName(name);
    }

    @GetMapping("/getById/{id}")
    public EmployeeDetails getById(@PathVariable long id) {
        return employeeRepo.findById(id);
    }

    @GetMapping("/getNameById/{id}")
    public String getNameById(@PathVariable long id) {

        EmployeeDetails employeeDetails = employeeRepo.findById(id);

        if (employeeDetails != null) {
            System.out.println(employeeDetails.getName());
            return employeeDetails.getName();
        } else {
            // Handle the case when the employee with the given ID is not found
            return null;
        }
    }

    @GetMapping("/getPulserateById/{id}")
    public Long getPulserateById(@PathVariable long id) {

        EmployeeDetails employeeDetails = employeeRepo.findById(id);

        if (employeeDetails != null) {
            System.out.println(employeeDetails.getName());
            return employeeDetails.getPulserate();
        } else {
            // Handle the case when the employee with the given ID is not found
            return null;
        }
    }

    @GetMapping("/getStepCountById/{id}")
    public Long getStepCountById(@PathVariable long id) {

        EmployeeDetails employeeDetails = employeeRepo.findById(id);

        if (employeeDetails != null) {
            System.out.println(employeeDetails.getName());
            return employeeDetails.getStepcount();
        } else {
            // Handle the case when the employee with the given ID is not found
            return null;
        }
    }

    @GetMapping("/getHeartbeatById/{id}")
    public Integer getHeartbeatById(@PathVariable long id) {
        EmployeeDetails employeeDetails = employeeRepo.findById(id);

        if (employeeDetails != null) {
            System.out.println(employeeDetails.getName());
            return Math.toIntExact(employeeDetails.getHeartbeat());
        } else {
            // Handle the case when the employee with the given ID is not found
            return null;
        }
    }


    @PostMapping("/savenew")
    public EmployeeDetails savenew(@RequestBody EmployeeDetails employeeDetails)
    {
        return employeeRepo.save(employeeDetails);
    }
}

2.) TestApplication.java:
package com.example.test;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class TestApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       SpringApplication.run(TestApplication.class, args);
    }

}

getPulserateById, getStepCountById and all such functions work in the flutter where I retrieve the pulse rate and step count from the database but getNameById is not working probably because pulse rate and step count and all are of long datatype but name is of String datatype in springboot
And here is the error that occurs while running the flutter code:
I/flutter ( 9262): Error fetching profile name: FormatException: Unexpected character(at character 1)
I/flutter ( 9262): Sophia Brown
I/flutter ( 9262): ^

and dont worry about the Elevated Button saying "Confirm", I have not set it up yet, The data is retrieved as soon as I enter the user id in the profile but only the name is not getting displayed in the emulator
Thank You
I checked whether the data from the server is in JSON Format and confirmed that its in JSON. And I also changed Future fetchProfileName(String userId) async to Future fetchProfileName(String userId) async but the error still persists

Can you try calling this api fn inside initState with sample userId to check if the api call is working correctly.

Thanks for replying, I finally resolved the issue. Thank You

If you have solved the issue. Kindly add the solution for others. It will be helpful for dev having same prblm
